# What algorithm is used in Adobe Lightroom for color noise reduction?

Tags: opencv

Adobe Lightroom has option called Color Noise Reduction and I want to implement same functionality. However I can't find anywhere which algorithm it is uses.

Anyone can point me in a right direction how to implement it? So far I tried to use OpenCV fas `Not-local Means Denoising Colored` algorithm, but it is not provide same result as I need

[image]

Comment: It seems as bilateral filter for chroma channels (use HSV). Some photo editors used wavelet-based noise reduction: for luma and chroma or only for chroma channels.

Comment: @Nuzhny yea, bilateral filter look pretty similar. Thank you. Move your comment into answer and I will accept it as correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as bilateral filter for chroma channels (use HSV).
Some photo editors used wavelet-based noise reduction: for luma and chroma or only for chroma channels.